# From MySQL to Access sql (using not in)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I need some help to transform sql code to sql access code,my code is:

```
    SELECT `HOTEL`.`NAME_H`,`ROOM`.`NUMBER_R`,`ROOM`.`FLOOR_R`
    FROM HOTEL, ROOM
    WHERE `HOTEL`.`CODE_H`=`ROOM`.`CODE_H`
    AND `HOTEL`.`TOWN_H`=`Athens`
    AND (`HOTEL`.`CODE_H`,`ROOM`.`NUMBER_R`)
    NOT IN (SELECT `CODE_H`,`NUMBER_R` FROM RESERVATION)
```

its not running in access,I don’t know how to use not in in ms,any ideas?
I have a problem and with another one,my code is:

```
    SELECT `ΟFFER`.`CODE_O`,`HOTEL`.`NAME_H`,`ROOMTYPE`.`NAME_RT`,MIN(`OFFER`.`PRICE_O`)
    FROM OFFER,HOTEL,ROOMTYPE
    WHERE `OFFER`.`CODE_H`=`HOTEL`.`CODE_H`
    AND `OFFER`.`CODE_RT`=`ROOMTYPE`.`CODE_RT`
    GROUP BY `CODE_O`
```

Comment: This code is not running in ms access...

Comment: If this is the actual code, it will not run in most DBMSes due to the backticks. Q1: Access probably doesn't support multi-column subqueries, try rewriting to NOT EXISTS. Q2: This is that stupid MySQL extension to allow aditional columns not in GROUP BY.

Comment: Can you remove the backticks and let us know what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that if I get the logic for the NOT IN clause right. If not, you still get the idea and you can adjust it.

```
SELECT HOTEL.NAME_H,ROOM.NUMBER_R,ROOM.FLOOR_R
FROM HOTEL, ROOM
WHERE HOTEL.CODE_H=ROOM.CODE_H
AND HOTEL.TOWN_H=Athens
AND HOTEL.CODE_H  NOT IN (SELECT CODE_H FROM RESERVATION) 
AND ROOM.NUMBER_R NOT IN (SELECT NUMBER_R FROM RESERVATION)
```

Comment: This will not return the same result, both `CODE_H` and `NUMBER_R` must match the same row from `RESERVATION`

Comment: How,i can do this?

Comment: That works fine based on the logic you have provided. However, if it is part of the logic to have the combination of CODE_H and NUMBER_R as a unique distinct entity then either there is another column more appropriate to filter on or you have to create one on yourself describing that relationship. Do some testing and see if that is necessary.

Comment: Κώστα,το ερώτημα που έχω είναι:\

Comment: Κώστα το ερώτημα που έχω είναι το εξής. Να βρεθεί για ποια δωμάτια ξενοδοχείων στην πόλη της Αθήνας δεν υπάρχει καταγεγραμμένη καμία κράτηση.Στο αποτέλεσμα να εκτυπωθεί το όνομα του ξενοδοχείου,ο αριθμός του δωματίου καθώς και ο όροφος στον οποίο βρίσκεται το δωμάτιο.